# How to get data form airhob api ? My request is giving me a 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I want to get flight informations from an Api called `airhob`(https://www.airhob.com/developers/api/docs).

To do that I´m using ReactJS and Axios to fetch data.

In the Api documentation, the header is only:

> apikey – Your sandbox or production API key
>
> mode - sandbox or production
>
> Content-Type - application/json

So to do that, I write the following code :

```
    var authOptions = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://dev-sandbox-api.airhob.com/sandboxapi/flights/v1.3/search',
        headers: {
                'Content-Type' :  'application/json',
                'apikey': 'MyApiKey',
                'mode' : 'sandbox'
              },

        data:{

                 "TripType": "O",
                  "NoOfAdults": 1, 
                  "NoOfChilds": 0, 
                  "NoOfInfants": 0,
                   "ClassType": "Economy", 
                   "OriginDestination": [
                        { "Origin": "SFO", 
                        "Destination": "LAX", 
                        "TravelDate": "04/23/2018" } 
                    ], 
                    "Currency": "USD" 

            },
        json: true
      };

        return axios(authOptions)
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);

        })
        .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
```

So the result for this code should display all flight to Los Angeles in my console.

Comment: I Hope apikey is Fake One Else Please Remove it.

Comment: If you're getting a 401, then that means you're unauthorized